# WPF DataVisualization Chart axis binding throws error

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, data-binding, data-visualization

I am using WPF DataVisualization Chart control in my WPF application.
In application we are binding

```
Minimum="{Binding GraphData.XMin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
Maximum="{Binding GraphData.XMax, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
Interval="{Binding GraphData.XInterval, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

all three values.
The problem is when we are updating GraphData, chart throws error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The minimum value must be smaller than or equal to the maximum value.'

the minimum and maximum values are fine but they are lesser than previous values.

I have searched a lot but not found any related documentation or post.

Comment: If the new values are smaller than the existing ones, you should set set the `XMin` property before you set the `XMax` property. And if the new values are larger than the existing ones, you should set the `XMax` property first.

Comment: I tried that one also. it is not working in my case. I updated code where I am updating DataContext; before it I am updating DataContext=null; then adding new DataContext.

Comment: Are you sure that the value of `XMin` is actually smaller than the value of `XMax`?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it many times.  but error occurs when chart's current context contains XMin greater than XMax of new context or vice versa. so when I update DataCOntext to null and then attached new context it worked fine.